# How can I resolve MS teams login issue?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I can login to MS Teams with the login credentials provided by my new workplace in browser-based environment (chrome), but I am not able to login in Windows App meant for MS Teams. As soon as I entered my email id, I am getting the following error:

[Error window 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcd4s.png)

Once I pressed the Ok button, the following error message show up:

[Error window 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiZkU.png)

Even after pressing OK button in the above message, the following blank window appears:

[Blank Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhNJt.png)

In the same Windows App, if I attempt to login using my friend's login credentials, it works fine.

Kindly help me out in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us. We are the developer support team for Microsoft teams focused on helping developers resolve their code issues. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.